# IFNULL is not working

Tags: mysql, null

Hi I am working with mysqli to replace a default value on the table if the data from the database is NULL. I already tried it on PHPmyAdmin and it's working but not on my code :(

Here's my SELECT query:

```
$query="SELECT pro_id, pro_name, unit_name, cat_name, IFNULL(quantity,'empty') AS quantity FROM products, unit, categories WHERE products.unit=unit.unit_id AND products.pro_cat=categories.cat_id";
```

Comment: The table returns empty. MySQL said: Documentation

#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: try specifying the table.column value for the (IFNULL(quantity, ...) section. perhaps the error is caused by the table alias.

Comment: IFNULL(products.quantity,'empty') AS quantity  is also not working

Comment: try dropping the 'AS' after the IFNULL and see if that works.

Comment: What happens if you run this:

SELECT products.pro_id, products.pro_name, products.unit_name, products.cat_name, IFNULL(products.quantity,'empty') AS quantity FROM products
JOIN unit ON products.unit = unit.unit_id
JOIN categories ON products.pro_cat = categories.cat_id

See if that changes anything. I believe that your syntax is right given you can run it on PHPMyAdmin, but you never quite know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as one of your comments seems to indicate, the error you're getting is:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'
```

then it's a simple typo. [`ISNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) is not the same as [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

The former returns a truth value if its *one* argument is null.

The latter returns the second argument if the first is null, otherwise it returns the first argument.

You can see this if you put the following code into SqlFiddle:

```
-- DDL
create table xyzzy (plugh int);
insert into  xyzzy (plugh)       values (null);
insert into  xyzzy (plugh)       values (42);

select plugh, isnull(plugh)    from xyzzy;
select plugh, ifnull(plugh,-1) from xyzzy;
select plugh, isnull(plugh,-1) from xyzzy;
```

The output is as expected for the first two select statements while the third generates the error you describe:

```
plugh   isnull(plugh)
------  -------------
(null)  1
42      0

plugh   ifnull(plugh,-1)
------  ----------------
(null)  -1
42      42

Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'
```