# Mysql query, i had write a IFNULL condition ,but its showing empty space instead of Not Available (im using phpmyadmin 4.0 )

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
select IFNULL(idtag,'Not Available') parentidtag  from authorisation;
```

Mysql query where the idtag default value is null, so i had write a condition ifnull is to show as 'not available' ,but it is showing as ' 'empty spaces in table(im using phpmyadmin 4.0 )

Comment: maybe here some good info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636752/ifnull-is-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the data in question is not really `NULL`, but rather is empty string `''`.  Instead, try the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IFNULL(idtag, '') = '' THEN 'Not Available' ELSE idtag END
FROM authorisation
```